# how to omit attributes in ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, ember.js, ember-data

To keep Ember focussed and to minimize data transfer, I "cached" some attributes on some models. Example: Because I only need the name of an author, I cache it to the book:

In Rails: Book has_one :author
In Ember: Book author_name: DS.attr("string")

So in Rails I compute the author_name and send it with the json data.

Now if I try to send data back to the server, I need to omit the cached attributes.

I tried overriding "serialize" in the Book model but that had no effect (which struck me as odd and illogical).

Eventually I've overridden the addAttribute in my adapter. So I now use:

```
adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend
    addAttribute: (hash, key, value)->
      cached_keys = [ "author_name", "more" ]
      this._super(hash, key, value) unless cached_keys.contains(key)
```

But now the attributes aren't linked to "Book" anymore. Even more, I have more cached attributes on other models, but in here they are all mixed together. I can't imagine this is the best way to solve the problem. Any better ideas?

Comment: I would tag this question with `ember-data`.

Comment: @MehulKar I've added ember-data, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on latest master, but I override `addAttributes` as opposed to `addAttribute`. Inside that I set up a switch statement to use `record.constructor` to serialize or not serialize values.

**Example:**

```
App.Serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend
  addAttributes: (data, record) ->
    switch record.constructor
      when App.Post
        record.eachAttribute (name, attribute) =>
          @_addAttribute(data, record, name, attribute.type) if name != "created_at"
      else
        @_super(data,record)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try that soon. It certainly looks better. Is there a reason why Ember doesn't use the posts serialize method? (or even why you don't on your fifth line: record.serialize + override serialize in the post class).

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not sure. Looks like `DS.Model` has a `serialize` function and it basically calls the `DS.Store`'s serialize function, which calls the adapter, which calls the serializer, and eventually lands up here. Not sure where/how the chain begins though.